# Как закрыть подменю, при повторном клике?

Tags: javascript

```js
var ACTIVE = 'active';
$(".main-navigation > ul > li").on('click', function() {
  $(".main-navigation > ul > li").removeClass(ACTIVE);
  $(this).addClass(ACTIVE);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.maga-menu__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.active .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul class="maga-menu__list">
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a>Пункт 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a>Пункт 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a>Пункт 3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Я же вам сказал попробовать `toggleClass`. Не подошло? Если нет, что именно пошло не так?

Comment: @EzioMercer ему надо два в одном: 1 - toggle при клике на один и тот же пункт, 2- закрытие всех и открытие кликнутого. Если просто сделать toggleClass - не сработает, т.к. удаляется везде вначале класс

Comment: `var ACTIVE = 'active';
  $(".main-navigation > ul > li").on('click', function() {
    $(".main-navigation > ul > li").removeClass(ACTIVE);
    $(this).toggleClass(ACTIVE);
  });`
не работает

Comment: @КонстантинЖевжик не работает, потому что там не нужен `$(".main-navigation > ul > li").removeClass(ACTIVE);` перед `$(this).toggleClass(ACTIVE);`

Comment: `var ACTIVE = 'active';
  $(".main-navigation > ul > li").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass(ACTIVE);
  });`

И тут возникает ошибка, оба подменю одновременно открываются, а так не должно быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем, как убрать у всех класс `active`, занесём значение состояния кликнутого элемента в переменную. И потом проверим, если он был активным до убираения классов - то убираем активность, если не был - ставим

Трюк тут заключается именно в запоминании состояния **ДО** удаления класса `active` со всех элементов

```js
var ACTIVE = 'active';
$(".main-navigation > ul > li").on('click', function() {
  let clickedElementIsActive = $(this).hasClass(ACTIVE);  
  $(".main-navigation > ul > li").removeClass(ACTIVE);
  
  // Длинная версия
  // clickedElementIsActive ? $(this).removeClass(ACTIVE): $(this).addClass(ACTIVE);
  
  // Короткая версия
  $(this).toggleClass(ACTIVE, !clickedElementIsActive);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.maga-menu__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.active .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul class="maga-menu__list">
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a>Пункт 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a>Пункт 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu__item">
      <a>Пункт 3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a>Под пункт 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `clickedElementIsActive` можно передать в `toggleClass` :)

Comment: Точно, постоянно забываю эту шнягу

Comment: ....Добавил....

Comment: Спасибо :))))))

Comment: Спасибо! Спасли просто)